# Como Posso impedir o usuario de apertar o botão varias vezes seguidas em PYQT5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

[Resolvido]Eu sou bem iniciante em pyqt, principalmente em python, eu estou com um problema olhei em varios foruns, como eu consigo impedir o usuario de apertar o botão multiplas vezes seguidas?
Já tentei usar o disable() e depois habilitar denovo, tentei desconectar e depois conectar, até tentei usar o hide(), mas como minha função rola na mesma thread assim que a função acaba ele excetua as "clickadas" que fiz durante esse tempo, vi na internet que eu teria que fazer uma outra thread para minha função e na principal receber as clickadas desabilitadas, mas como eu disse eu sou bem iniciante em python e não consegui achar nada especifico, se alguem poder me mandar algum material, ou tiver outra solução para o meu problema, eu agradeceria.
meu codigo:

```
self.botler_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.sendData("$LM1"))
def sendData(self, text):
        print("Sending data")
        print(text)
```

Comment: Você pode tentar usar o disable, pra desabilitar o botão após o clique

Comment: não funciona, pois os eventos de clciks ficaram esperando os botoes serem habilitados denovo

Comment: Porque vc não cria uma variável para contar os clicks e se ela for maior que 1 vc ignorar o click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Resolvido]Não funciona  kkk , pois como está rolando na mesma thread  as clickadas que eu fiz enquanto o evento estava acontecendo ficam esperando o botao ficar habilitado denovo, o que eu estou tetando fazer agora e criar uma outra thread pra habilitar ele denovo, mas estou com problema no finish
Pois eu criei o metodo botoesclickados, que quando eu clickar ele vai entrar nessa função vai iniciar minha thread e assim que ela acabar irá habiltiar denovo mas ela não me manda o sinal de finalizada  def botoesclickados(self):

```
    self.send = sendDataThread()
        self.send.start()
        self.botler_1.setEnabled(False)
        self.send.finished.connect(lambda: self.libera)
    
    def libera(self):
        self.botler_1.setEnabled(True)

class sendDataThread(QThread):
    def run(self):
        for x in range (5):
            print(x)
            time.sleep(1)
```

EDIT: Consegui resolver tirando o lambda da linha
self.send.finished.connect(lambda: self.libera)
self.send.finished.connect(self.libera)